# Geometry Dash: Having Problems

Tags: geometry-dash

I am having several problems with geometry dash (update 2.0). The game starts up just fine, and I don't have limited access to the game, but whenever I tap the profile button, it always says "something went wrong...". If I hit the refresh button, then weird stats will come up. They are: 88 Stars, 20 Secret Coins, 0 User Coins, 0 Demon Levels, and the basic icons with red and blue. What's wrong, and what can I do to fix it?

Also, a while back I made an account. The problem was when I posted a level, the last letter was cut off. So, I changed my username, but my shown username was still the same. Any idea why?

I know I'm asking for a lot, but I would be grateful for any help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Apple or Android? I would suggest either (Apple) re-downloading the app or (Android) perhaps emptying the cache.

Comment: What Ben said, with the added option of: "PC". Also, does this problem persist after wiping the data/reinstalling and using a new account?

Comment: I am using apple, and no other devices. I tried saving and unlinking my account, then deleting and re-downloading the app, but it didn't work. I also tried making a new account, but I it would never come off of "something went wrong...", so is it my device?

Answer (score 3):

I know the answer only for the not changing name.

It happened also to me, and I think it is normal. You have just to wait a bit (2 - 3 weeks) and it will fix itself. That means you probably already have your name fixed. If not, then I don't know any other solutions.