# In Game name doesn't change

Tags: geometry-dash

So I changed my name on my profile but when I go to it in the leaderboards, it still has my old name instead of my new one. Does anyone know how to fix this? Thanks!

Comment: I flagged this as a duplicate of: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/238833/will-changing-my-geometry-dash-username-affect-my-levels?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @user181699 well unflag it because it's not at all even similar

Answer (score 1):

As I have already said [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/233629/geometry-dash-having-problems), it happened also to me, and I think it is normal. You have just to wait a bit (2 - 3 weeks) and it will fix itself. That means you probably already have your name fixed. If not, then I don't know any other solutions.